# Path of a folder in my Android Project

Tags: android, path, jsch

In my android app I have created a "raw" folder inside /res folder (/res/raw). The "raw" folder contains a file (a public/private key file to connect sftp without password).

I am using Jsch library to connect to sftp using public/private key. For setting the key file I need a path where my key file is. The Jsch method for setting private key file path is:

```
    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    ssh.addIdentity("path/to/key/file/filename");
```

What path should I pass for key file ? Passing "res/raw/filename" gives `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/raw/firmware_key (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For setting the key file I need a path where my key file is.

Then you will need to copy the resource out to a file. There is no file for the resource -- it is a bunch of bytes in an APK file. Use `getResources().openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream` that you can use to copy the data to a file in internal storage.

Comment: I have copied a data to a file and store it in internal storage (/files folder). Now what should be the path to pass ?

Comment: @rizzz86: You pass the path to the file you created. For example, if you used `getFilesDir()` as the basis for creating a `File` that you copied the data into, you would use `getAbsolutePath()` on that `File` object, just as you would in any other Java development. Also, I hope that you will never distribute this app, as anyone can trivially reverse engineer it to get at your SSH credentials.

Comment: Actually I have used openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) to write data in file. Thanks for pointing out the reverse engineering threat.

Comment: @rizzz86: Then `new File(getFilesDir(), "filename"))` will give you a `File` object, on which you can call `getAbsolutePath()` to get a path to the file.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare it works. I was initially hardcoding the path like "/data/data/com.mypackage.app/files/filename" but now I have replaced it with new File(getFilesDir(), "filename").getAbsolutePath(). So atleast it is finding the file now but giving Auth Fail error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
ssh.addIdentity("android.resource://com.mypackage.myapp/raw/firmware_key");
```

where `com.mypackage.myapp` is your application root package.

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: Setting "android.resource://com.firmware.client/res/raw/firmware_key" and "android.resource://com.firmware.client/raw/firmware_key" both gives java.io.FileNotFoundException